# String Index Out of Range when comparing characters

Tags: python

I am simply trying to compare one character in a string to its neighbor, but I keep getting a string index out of range error. I can't figure this out.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
current = ""
previous = ""
for letter in range(0,len(s)):
    if s[letter] <= s[letter+1]:
        current += s[letter]
print(current)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code?  Hint run `list(range(0,len(s)))` and see what indices you'll be using.  Particularly when you try `s[letter+1]`

Comment: ```for letter in range(0,len(s)-1):``` is the way to go. Your code checks for elements which is at a position next to your current one. You add 1 to it. But at the end, there are no more elements but still you check for it. This cause python to throw index error

Comment: That worked perfectly, Sujay.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement was unnecessary. On the last iteration of the loop, `s[letter+1]` was throwing an error because that index of the string didn't exist. At that point, `letter` was equal to the length of your string, `s`. `letter+1` was one higher than the length, so the index didn't exist.

There is no need to compare the value of `letter` to the length of `s` in the if statement because the loop would end before `letter` is greater than the length of `s`.

Solution:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
current = ""
previous = ""
for letter in range(0,len(s)):
    current += s[letter]
print(current)
```

Answer (score 0):

while @sedavidw is completely right pointing out the indexing issue, it is not a very pythonic way of doing such a comparison. I'd do something like:

```
current = ''.join(letter for letter, next_letter in zip(s, s[1:]) 
                  if letter <= next_letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to print a letter only if the previous one is less than the current one. The index out of bounds occur because the last index points to (l) but index + 1 points to nothing.

Here is my solution:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl' 
current = "" 
previous = "" 
for letter in range(0,len(s)): 
   if letter + 1 < len(s): # this is important to prevent the index out of bounds error
       if s[letter] <= s[letter+1]: 
           current += s[letter] 
 print(current)

Output: abbbeggak
```

Comment: I guess simply `range(0,len(s)-1)` would be better, if you want to go this way